CameraX does not work in direct boot mode
When trying to launch the camera in direct boot state using CameraX I get the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraX is not configured properly. The most likely cause is you did not include a default implementation in your build such as 'camera-camera2'.
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.<init> (CameraX.java:107)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.getOrCreateCameraXInstance (ProcessCameraProvider.java:196)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance (ProcessCameraProvider.java:182)

It happens when I call:
val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)

When trying to launch after unlocking the device after restart (i.e. exiting direct boot mode) the code works and camera works fine.
How to fix this?

If the problem is due to the metadata problem @sweak mentioned, another way to handle this can be initializing CameraX through the ProcessCameraProvider#configureInstance and Camera2Config#defaultConfig() API.
ProcessCameraProvider.configureInstance(Camera2Config.defaultConfig())
val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)


Nice one! It works!

The issue was that the CameraX library is not suited to work under the direct boot conditions. More specifically when calling ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context), when configuring the camera, the following code was called in the CameraX internals (you can look it up in the CameraX source code - line ~180):
ServiceInfo serviceInfo = appContext.getPackageManager().getServiceInfo(
        new ComponentName(appContext, MetadataHolderService.class),
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA | PackageManager.MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);

This code was trying to retrieve the CameraXConfig.Provider through meta-data provided by implementation library but instead was throwing PackageManager.NameNotFoundException which failed the whole camera initialization process.
At this point I've realized I shouldn't really expect CameraX maintainers to address this issue so I've created a workaround that would, before launching the camera, check whether we are operating in the direct boot mode using UserManager.isUserUnlocked:
val userManager = getSystemService(USER_SERVICE) as UserManager

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N &&
    !userManager.isUserUnlocked
) {
    // We are in the direct boot mode - request the user to unlock the device first...
}

This would avoid the crash as the camera would be launched after unlocking the device.
